# Qt 4 On Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, qt4, qt5

I cant seem to find the "qt 4 sdk" installer for ubuntu 13.04. I need one that will install and allow me to have the qt creator that you get through the software center be able to detect qt 4 and 5 based projects. Has any one found any out of the box solutions for this. Or are there any instructions out there on how to get the ubuntu 13.04 version of qtcreator to recognize qt 4 projects?

Comment: There is this link, http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Qt-SDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux but one would assume that there would be a .deb installer for this.

Comment: QtCreator is SDK version agnostic, the choice of build libraries is set in the .pro.user file, even old version of QtCreator can run the newest SDK and vice versa. Do you get any specific errors?

Comment: I am aware of this fact, it is just a matter of being able to know which package to install to get the qt4 libs installed. Right now I only have access to qt5 libs. As for build errors using qmake from qt5 I have several when I include a header library that includes GL/glx.h.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
apt-cache search libqt4
```

That should give you a list of all the packages needed to get the Qt 4 libs.
Should include:

```
libqt4-dev
libqt4-core
libqt4-gui
...etc
```

Comment: Software Center has them just search for qmake. Easier this way for newbs like me.